# Figuring out what plugin is messing with my input

Tags: debugging

This is a more general question so I would like to know how to actually debug something like this. Suppose that I have some plugin that does section completion as code is being written. For example this can be bracket completion - I type { and } appears as well.

How can I actually find out which lisp function is making these modifications to the buffer? Is there some way to list all hooks being called during text entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would *start* with <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>{</kbd> to see what command <kbd>{</kbd> is bound to in the buffer in question, as it might well be bound to some hypothetical `insert-both-{-and-}` command.

If the behaviour is triggered by keys which are bound to `self-insert-command` then the hook you are looking for is rather likely to be <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `post-self-insert-hook`

`post-command-hook` is a more generic possibility, and then there are <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Change Hooks` which are again very general (and trickier to use).

---

The Emacs parlance for functionality whereby additional things happen automatically when you insert certain characters is "electric"; so an alternative in a situation like this one would be:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `apropos-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `electric` <kbd>RET</kbd>

or perhaps:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `apropos-command` <kbd>RET</kbd> `electric.*mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>

In your case, I would suspect you have enabled either `electric-pair-mode` (which is a global minor mode) or `electric-pair-local-mode` (which is the buffer-local equivalent).

See also <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Matching`